# Compare HashMap Values structured as List

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, compare

I have a HashMap structured like

```
{a=[test], b=[test, test2]}
```

I want to compare entry values (test, test2) with each other and if any entry has same value with another one, I need to return their keys and the equal value. I want to do this in Java.

Comment: Please share what did you try so far.

Answer (score 1):

Simply reverse the `Map`, use your values as grouping key for the original keys where the value repeat.

```java
Map<KeysClass, List<ValuesClass>> original = ....
Map<ValuesClass, List<KeysClass>> keysGroupedPerValue = new HashMap<>();

for(Entry<KeysClass, List<ValuesClass> entry : original) {
   for(ValuesClass value : entry.getValue()) {
      List<KeysClass> keysHavingValue = keysGroupedPerValue.computeIfAbsent(value, val -> new ArrayList<>());
      keysHavingValues.add(entry.getKey());
   }
}
```

There are also more elegant solutions using the `Stream` and `Collector` APIs.